# IWebElement.SendKeys() incomplete

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I'm experiencing the problem that IWebElement.SendKeys() does not fill entire input field that I'm aiming. Here is the code example:

```
...
IWebElement el1 = driver.FindElemenet(By.Id("el1Id"));
IWebElement el2 = driver.FindElemenet(By.Id("el2Id"));
el1.SendKeys("sometext");
el2.SendKeys("someothertext");
...
```

So, sometimes, instead of filling el1Id with "sometext", it proceeds with el2Id and in el1Id it is only filled "somet" for example. This is happening in like 30% of cases, number of typed characters differs from case to case. I'm using Firefox 8.0

Comment: have you tried finishing el1.SendKeys before searching for the next element?

Comment: add "Thread.Sleep(1000);" and try again - I guess it's some kind of timing problem

Comment: I made this change and started my tests, and seem like this eliminated problematic behavior. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more robust just add a waiting before the next step.

Something like:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

or

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

That's will do the job.